# Dynamically adding an int to a textView

Tags: android, xml, textview

This may seem like a stupid question, but for some reason i just can't figure it out- i have a few textViews i add text from an Object all the string fields are added fine. but when i try to add a int to the textView it crashes my application.

heres my code

```
firstLineOfAddress.setText(addline);
town.setText(town2);
county.setText(county2);
postCode.setText(post);
 // the three strings up above work fine if i comment the  three below out
 // ask , current, done are all ints
askingPrice.setText(ask);
currentOffer.setText(current);
doneUpValue.setText(done);
```

Comment: what is exactly problem..

Comment: `int` will be added to textview as a `textView.setText(""+intValue);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set like this:

```
textView.setText(10+"");
```

In your code replace this:

```
askingPrice.setText(ask);
currentOffer.setText(current);
doneUpValue.setText(done);
```

with

```
askingPrice.setText(ask+"");
currentOffer.setText(current+"");
doneUpValue.setText(done+"");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have to **convert your int to String**. To convert your int to String, use :

```
Integer.toString(myInt)
```

**or**

```
String.valueOf(myint)
```

So it would be `askingPrice.setText(Integer.toString(myInt))`

Answer (score 1):

when you add any Integer number the call this...

```
    textview.setText(""+value);
```

OR

```
   textview.setText(String.valueOf(value));
```

where `value` is a Integer.

Answer (score 0):

try to convert it to a `String` perhaps .

```
askingPrice.setText(String.format("%d",ask));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the text value as a String. Convert it as so:

```
askingPrice.setText(String.valueOf(ask));
currentOffer.setText(String.valueOf(current));
doneUpValue.setText(String.valueOf(done));
```

Answer (score 0):

well trying above scenario like this 
   `int text=0;`
   TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.test);
   `tv.setText(text);`

throws exception as
(26955): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.highactivity/com.example.highactivity.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0

because while passing integer in set text it takes as resource id.At run time search for resource id =0 but there wont be any resource id like that so it throws exception will leads to app crashes.convert int to string if you need to display integer